# drawing a digital signal

Tags: matlab

Using matlab can we draw a digital signal out of an array that contains numbers ? Is there a way to convert each number to binary "dec2bin" and then draw it ?

Comment: Are you looking for "plot(array)" ?

Comment: actually the array only contains decimal numbers I want to draw the binary numbers corresponding to each one of them to get a digital signal .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dec2bin`, but remember that this gives you a set of strings, i.e. character data.  So do the following:

```
dec2bin(x, NUM_BITS) - '0'
```

You can now plot each column of this.

Comment: Well I'm actually stuck in the plotting process I have a decimal number "in fact array of decimal numbers" and when I convert it into binary "dec2bin" all I have is a string , so what is the way to draw a string of zeros and ones taking in consideration that the plot of each string must appear once the one before it ends. Thanks a lot for the reply. I appreciate it .